# Does the iphone have a local webserver or can I download a third party one?

Tags: iphone, webserver

Does the iphone have a local webserver or can I download a third party one?

Comment: No I mean a webserver so I can run html files through http://localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not allow any third party codeinterpreters or environments to be installed on iOS, so if you want to run PHP, Python, Ruby or a similar language, you are out of luck. If you are just trying to parse and display HTML and CSS, then you should use the UIWebView object. UIWebView class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UIWebView, you should be able to simply pass the requisite file/html to it.

Answer (score 0):

Jailbreak your iPhone and then you can install Apache pretty easily. PHP is also in the repositories as well if you want to run webapps or something else.

See: http://idude.org/2007/11/07/an-iphone-powered-apache-web-server-with-php/

For a more basic setup that does not require you to jailbreak, there is software called ServersMan: http://itunes.apple.com/app/serversman/id302133974?mt=8
I believe this is one of those apps that runs a HTTP/WebDAV server to act as a "USB stick" for transferring files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, just use the built in Apache and your /Sites folder. Otherwise, run a simple web framework like Sinatra or Rails.